# ASP.NET View Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor

I created a Web API project in Visual Studio. I am using attribute routing. Here is the controller under Controllers folder:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Registration
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(string platform)
    {

         return View("~/Views/Registration/CreateUser.cshtml", platform);
    }
}
```

When I call the `CreateUser` action by the URL `http://localhost/application` it works but when I try to pass a query string parameter by the URL `http://localhost/application?platform=android`, it gives the following error:

> *The view '~/Views/Registration/CreateUser.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched:*
>
> *~/Views/Registration/CreateUser.cshtml*
>
> *~/Views/Registration/android.master*
>
> *~/Views/Shared/android.master*
>
> *~/Views/Registration/android.cshtml*
>
> *~/Views/Registration/android.vbhtml*
>
> *~/Views/Shared/android.cshtml*
>
> *~/Views/Shared/android.vbhtml*

I cannot understand why it cannot find the view when it is there or why it even tries to find a view with the name of the query string parameter.

Comment: This code should work fine. Are you sure the view file is included in the project/solution ?

Comment: You shouldnt need the entire path of the view in return view. Also, why do you have an empty route decorator on top?

Comment: while the entire path is not needed, It will not break anything.It should still work. The empty route is to make this action the default.

Comment: Yes, the view file is included in the project. As I mentioned, when I do not use the query string it works just fine. The problem occurs when the query string is not empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can probably find the view. It is the Master page that it can't find.

That is because you are using the

```
class Controller : ... {
    ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName);
}
```

overload method, which

> Creates a System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult object using the **view name** and
>   **master-page name** that renders a view to the response.

the clue was the fact that it included the parameter value in the search for a view. Because you passed platform parameter was a string, it matched the method called to the one that used the `string viewName` and `string masterName` parameters.

`Controller` has many over loads for the `ViewResult View()` method. In this case you probably wanted to pass the `platform` as an object model. You can fix this by using named arguments which would avoid the confusion by letting the compiler know which overload method you intended to call....

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller {
    // GET: Registration
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(string platform) {
         return View("~/Views/Registration/CreateUser.cshtml", model: platform);
    }
}
```

From there everything should work as expected